# Formatting regular expression code in the argument of \verb

Tags: verbatim, regular-expressions

I have some difficulties with formatting regular expressions in the argument of `\verb`. Thank you for any help.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm, paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}X} % new

\input{structure.cls} %

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htp]                 % new
    \small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont  % reduce interline spaces
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}           % new
    \setcellgapes{2pt}                  % new
    \makegapedcells
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|L{4cm}|l|} % new
            \hline
                \bfseries{Pour trouver} & \bfseries\makecell{RegEx à utiliser} & \bfseries{Exemple} \\
            \hline
                E-mail & \verb+[^[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,3}\$]+ & f.guinko@gzvm.bf \\
            \hline
                Numéros de sécurité sociale américains & \verb+[^[a-z]+\$]+ & 513-84-7329 \\
            \hline
                Adresses IPV4 & \verb+[^[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,3}\$]+ & 212.23.2.110\\
            \hline
                Dates au format MM/JJ/AAAA & \verb+[^\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}\$]+ & Un seul mot non vide en minuscule \\
            \hline
                Numéros de cartes Mastercard & \verb+[^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}\$]+ & Exemple \\
            \hline
                Numéros de cartes Visa & \verb+[\b([4]\d{3}[\s]\d{4}[\s]\d{4}[\s]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}[-]\d{4}[-]\d{4}[-]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}[.]\d{4}[.]\d{4}[.]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}\d{4}\d{4}\d{4})\b]+ & Exemple \\
            \hline
                Numéros de cartes American Express & \verb+[^3[47][0-9]{13}\$]+ & Exemple \\
            \hline
                Codes ZIP US & \verb+[^((\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})|([A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d))\$]+ & Exemple \\
            \hline
                Chemins d’accès à des fichiers & \verb+[\\[^\\]+\$]+\$]+ & Exemple \\
            \hline
                URL & \verb+[(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9\%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?<<>>""'']))]+ & Exemple
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Exemples d'expressions régulières couramment utilisées}\label{tab:regexCourammentUtilisees}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Header of Latex file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=29cm, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont} %Sutilise avec \usepackage{amsmath} pour la commande $\text{\ding{113}}  \Delta$
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} % Pour \begin{enumerate}a)
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{paracol} %Permet de diviser la page en 2 colonnes
\usepackage{titlesec} %Pour modifier le fomat du titre de section subparagraph
\usepackage{cancel} %Pour écrire chiffres barrés

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}X} % new
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}

\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' env.
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{xurl}      % for '\path' macro, allow line breaks at arbitrary points

\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\bfseries\itshape} %Modification du fomat du titre de section subparagraph

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathsf{OT1}{lcmss}{m}{n}
```

Comment: `{tabularx}` does not allow verbatim elements. You should try `{NiceTabularxX}` of `nicematrix` which allows those elements (but you need several compilations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `+` inside the verbatim text delimited by `\verb+...+. As a delimiter you must use a character that doesn't appear in the verbatim text.

I suggest `"` that's unlikely to appear in regexes, but because of Murphy's law it does appear in the last one! (I used `T`.)

Also, you need to break lines. I'd make three equal size `L` columns (by the way, your definition requires an argument that's not used, so I removed it) and use `fvextra` features, see the code.

Of course, I'd also recommend to remove the vertical rules, but see below for a more appealing version.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm, paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % new

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp] % new

\linespread{0.84}
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}   % new
\setcellgapes{2pt}  % new
\makegapedcells
\fvset{breaklines,breakanywhere,breakanywheresymbolpre={}}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|L|L|L|} % new
\hline
\bfseries Pour trouver & \bfseries RegEx à utiliser & \bfseries Exemple \\
\hline
E-mail & \Verb"[^[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,3}\$]" & f.guinko@gzvm.bf \\
\hline
Numéros de sécurité sociale américains & \Verb"[^[a-z]+\$]" & 513-84-7329 \\
\hline
Adresses IPV4 & \Verb"[^[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,3}\$]" & 212.23.2.110\\
\hline
Dates au format MM/JJ/AAAA & \Verb"[^\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}\$]" & Un seul mot non vide en minuscule \\
\hline
Numéros de cartes Mastercard & \Verb"[^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}\$]" & Exemple \\
\hline
Numéros de cartes Visa & \Verb"[\b([4]\d{3}[\s]\d{4}[\s]\d{4}[\s]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}[-]\d{4}[-]\d{4}[-]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}[.]\d{4}[.]\d{4}[.]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}\d{4}\d{4}\d{4})\b]" & Exemple \\
\hline
Numéros de cartes American Express & \Verb"[^3[47][0-9]{13}\$]" & Exemple \\
\hline
Codes ZIP US & \Verb"[^((\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})|([A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d))\$]" & Exemple \\
\hline
Chemins d’accès à des fichiers & \Verb"[\\[^\\]+\$]+\$]" & Exemple \\
\hline
URL & \Verb T[(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9\%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?<<>>""'']))]T & Exemple \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Exemples d'expressions régulières couramment utilisées}\label{tab:regexCourammentUtilisees}

\end{table}


\begin{table}[!htp] % new

\footnotesize\raggedright
\fvset{breaklines,breakanywhere,breakanywheresymbolpre={}}

\textbf{E-mail} \\
\Verb"[^[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,3}\$]" \\
\texttt{f.guinko@gzvm.bf}

\medskip

\textbf{Numéros de sécurité sociale américains} \\
\Verb"[^[a-z]+\$]" \\
513-84-7329

\medskip

\textbf{Adresses IPV4} \\
\Verb"[^[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,3}\$]" \\
212.23.2.110

\medskip

\textbf{Dates au format MM/JJ/AAAA} \\
\Verb"[^\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}\$]" \\
Exemple

\medskip

\textbf{Numéros de cartes Mastercard} \\
\Verb"[^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}\$]" \\
Exemple

\medskip

\textbf{Numéros de cartes Visa} \\
\Verb"[\b([4]\d{3}[\s]\d{4}[\s]\d{4}[\s]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}[-]\d{4}[-]\d{4}[-]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}[.]\d{4}[.]\d{4}[.]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}\d{4}\d{4}\d{4})\b]" \\
Exemple

\medskip

\textbf{Numéros de cartes American Express} \\
\Verb"[^3[47][0-9]{13}\$]" \\
Exemple

\medskip

\textbf{Codes ZIP US} \\
\Verb"[^((\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})|([A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d))\$]" \\
Exemple

\medskip

\textbf{Chemins d’accès à des fichiers} \\
\Verb"[\\[^\\]+\$]+\$]" \\
Exemple

\medskip

\textbf{URL} \\
\Verb T[(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9\%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?<<>>""'']))]T \\
Exemple

\caption{Exemples d'expressions régulières couramment utilisées}\label{tab:regexCourammentUtilisees}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 for a good use of the `fvextra` package. However, you shouldn't use `"` as the delimiter character for the final `\Verb` directive (the URL case), as the `"` character occurs (several times, in fact) inside the string, toward the very end. Three visual give-aways are (a) the final few characters of the regex string are suddenly rendered in serif glyphs, (b) there's an unnecessarily early line break in the next-to-last row, and (c) the final character of the regex string has somehow become `"` (instead of `]`). Suggestion: write `\Verb y...y`.

Comment: @Mico Darn! Too long regex!

Answer (score 4):

Your code fails for two separate reasons.

- The character that is used to mark the start and end of the verbatim-character string *must not occur* in the string itself. However, the delimiter character you employ in the `\verb`  directives --  `+` -- occurs inside several of the strings.
- `\verb` does not allow automatic line breaking. Embedding a `\verb` directive inside an `X`-type column will not overcome this.

There are two additional severe problems with your code: First, unless one has access to the file `structure.cls`, your code won't compile at all. Second, since your `tabularx` environment doesn't allow automatic line breaking in columns 1 and 3, there is simply no way your table can fit inside the text block.

What to do? First and foremost, I suggest you load the `xurl` package and replace all `\verb/.../` directives with `\path{...}` directives; this will (a) render the strings in a monospaced font and (b) allow line breaking at arbitary points. Second, do allow automatic line breaking in columns 1 and 3 as well. Third, do use landscape mode to render the table. Fourth, is it permissible to get rid of the instruction `\input{structure.cls}`? Finally, do consider giving the table a much more open "look" by getting rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines.

Aside: The `\path` macro is just like the `\url` macro, except that it won't convert its argument to a hyperlink in case the `hyperref` package is loaded.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm, paperheight=24cm,
            margin=2cm]{geometry} % set margins as appropriate
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' env.
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{xurl}      % for '\path' macro, allow line breaks at arbitrary points

%\input{structure.cls} % % huh?

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!htbp]     
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}  % default: 6pt
% 24cm - 2*2cm = 20cm = available width in landscape mode  
\begin{tabularx}{20cm}{@{} P{3.5cm} L P{3cm} @{}}
    \toprule
      \bfseries Pour trouver 
    & \bfseries RegEx à utiliser 
    & \bfseries Exemple \\
    \midrule
    E-mail 
    & \path{[^[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,3}\$]} 
    & f.guinko@gzvm.bf \\
    \addlinespace
    Numéros de sécurité sociale américains 
    & \path{[^[a-z]+\$]} 
    & 513-84-7329 \\
    \addlinespace
    Adresses IPV4 
    & \path{[^[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,3}\$]} 
    & 212.23.2.110\\
    \addlinespace
    Dates au format MM/JJ/AAAA 
    & \path{[^\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}\$]} 
    & Un seul mot non vide en minuscule \\
    \addlinespace
    Numéros de cartes Mastercard 
    & \path{[^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}\$]} 
    & Exemple \\
    \addlinespace
    Numéros de cartes Visa 
    & \path{[\b([4]\d{3}[\s]\d{4}[\s]\d{4}[\s]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}[-]\d{4}[-]\d{4}[-]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}[.]\d{4}[.]\d{4}[.]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}\d{4}\d{4}\d{4})\b]} 
    & Exemple \\
    \addlinespace
    Numéros de cartes American Express 
    & \path{[^3[47][0-9]{13}\$]} 
    & Exemple \\
    \addlinespace
    Codes ZIP US 
    & \path{[^((\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})|([A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d))\$]} 
    & Exemple \\
    \addlinespace
    Chemins d’accès à des fichiers 
    & \path{[\\[^\\]+\$]+\$]} 
    & Exemple \\
    \addlinespace
    URL 
    & \path{[(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9\%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?<<>>""'']))]} 
    & Exemple \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Exemples d'expressions régulières couramment utilisées}
\label{tab:regexCourammentUtilisees}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With your code I am getting the following error message ! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (3cm): `c' used.

Comment: @cProg - The code I posted does *not* generate errors. The error message you report in the comment suggests that you wrote `P(3cm)` instead of `P{3cm}`. Please confirm that you included the instruction `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}` in your preamble and that you wrote `P{3cm}` twice in the second argument of the `tabularx` environment.

Comment: I have copied your code entirely without changing anything in it. I have updated my question to add the Header, I mean the current preamble of my Latex file.

Comment: @cProg - Your claim that you "copied [my] code entirely without changing anything in it" is *incorrect*. My code has `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}`, whereas yours has `\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}X}`. By the way, it makes no sense to define the `L` column type to take an argument (an intended width, I would assume?) and then discard that argument. In fact, your definition is an open invitation to disaster -- which, sure enough, has occurred. The upshot? Do please use my setting, *viz*., `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}`

Answer (score 4):

There is no problems with verbatim in table when using OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]

\thistable{\verbchar X \def\_printinverbatim #1{\foreach#1\do{##1\hskip0ptplus1pt\relax}}}
\table pxto\hsize {|p{4cm\fL}|p{\tsize}|p{3cm\fL}|}{\crl
   \bf Pour trouver & \bf RegEx à utiliser & \bf Exemple \crl
    E-mail & X[^[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,3}\$]X & f.guinko@gzvm.bf \crl
    Numéros de sécurité sociale américains & X[^[a-z]+\$]X & 513-84-7329 \crl
    Adresses IPV4 & X[^[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,3}\$]X & 212.23.2.110 \crl
    Dates au format MM/JJ/AAAA & X[^\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}\$]X & Un seul mot non vide en minuscule \crl
    Numéros de cartes Mastercard & X[^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}\$]X & Exemple \crl
    Numéros de cartes Visa & X[\b([4]\d{3}[\s]\d{4}[\s]\d{4}[\s]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}[-]\d{4}[-]\d{4}[-]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}[.]\d{4}[.]\d{4}[.]\d{4}|[4]\d{3}\d{4}\d{4}\d{4})\b]X & Exemple \crl
    Numéros de cartes American Express & X[^3[47][0-9]{13}\$]X & Exemple \crl
    Codes ZIP US & X[^((\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})|([A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d))\$]X & Exemple \crl
    Chemins d’accès à des fichiers & X[\\[^\\]+\$]+\$]X & Exemple \crl
    URL & X[(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9\%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?<<>>""'']))]X & Exemple \crl
}
\bye
```

[image: table compiled with column of verbatim content in OpTeX]

Comment: I get an error when I try to compile this. `! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
$
<to be read again> 
^
l.1 ...4}) Numéros de cartes American Express & X[^`

Comment: Something lost from the `Numéros de cartes Visa` and `URL` lines, maybe? If I comment those, it's fine. I don't know anything about OpTeX, but the Visa line surely needs a `\crl`, even if the error is occurring before TeX gets that far.

Comment: @cfr yes, you are right. It was my problem with copy-pasting of very width line.

Comment: Yes, I edited when I realised it was copy-pasting and I could therefore infer what was missing and get it working.